# Huge delay in Email Notifications using Azure Communication Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-communication-services

I'm experiencing huge delay with Email Azure Communication Services. While SMS notifications are delivered fast, email notifications take long time to deliver. This behavior is consistently observed. Any ideas?

I moved that time consuming operation to a Hangfire job, so that I can track it. As you can see the Hangfire job is running for several minutes.

[image]

```cs
public sealed record EmailNotificationJobOptions(string Email, string Subject, string Body);

[Queue("critical")]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 5)]
public class EmailNotificationJob
{
    readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public EmailNotificationJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task Perform(EmailNotificationJobOptions jobOptions, PerformContext? performContext)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var emailClient =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AzureEmailClient>();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobOptions.Email))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Email address is empty.");
        }

        await emailClient.SendAsync(jobOptions.Subject, jobOptions.Body, jobOptions.Email);
    }
}

public sealed class AzureEmailClient
{
    readonly string _from;
    readonly EmailClient _emailClient;

    public AzureEmailClient(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _from = configuration[ConfigurationKeys.AzureCommunicationServicesFromEmail];
        _emailClient = configuration.CreateEmailClient();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string subject, string message, string recipient, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var emailContent = new EmailContent(subject) { Html = message };
        var emailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress> { new(recipient) };
        var emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(emailAddresses);
        var emailMessage = new EmailMessage(_from, emailRecipients, emailContent);

        await _emailClient.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Started, emailMessage, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Will leave the code for SMS notifications too

```cs
public sealed record SmsNotificationJobOptions(string PhoneNumber, string Body);

[Queue("critical")]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 5)]
public class SmsNotificationJob
{
    readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SmsNotificationJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task Perform(SmsNotificationJobOptions jobOptions, PerformContext? performContext)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var smsClient =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AzureSmsClient>();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobOptions.PhoneNumber))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Phone number is empty.");
        }

        await smsClient.SendAsync(jobOptions.Body, jobOptions.PhoneNumber.ToE164());
    }
}

public sealed class AzureSmsClient
{
    readonly string _from;
    readonly SmsClient _smsClient;

    public AzureSmsClient(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _from = configuration[ConfigurationKeys.AzureCommunicationServicesFromPhoneNumber];
        _smsClient = configuration.CreateSmsClient();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string message, string recipient, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
        => await _smsClient.SendAsync(_from, recipient, message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: doesn't seems any issue in the code. If you're sending a lot of emails in a short period, you might be getting throttled. SMS might have a different rate limit than email. write a simple test application that only send email using Azure Communication Services.  Implement logging in your `AzureEmailClient` and `AzureSmsClient` classes, especially around the send methods. This can help in understanding if the delay is during the API call to Azure or somewhere else. Check if there are any spikes in latency or error rates at azure communication on portal.